# When you undo a Favorite vote, the number is decreased by 2 instead of by 1

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, ios-app

I've encountered a bug in the StackExchange application for iPhone.

When viewing a question with more than 1 favorites:

If you click "Favorite", the number increments by one (as it should be).
If you click "Favorite" again in order to cancel, the number is decreased by 2 instead of by 1, but it also happens when I unfavorite a question and then favorite it again.

I've checked this behavior on my Ubuntu laptop using Chrome and when I click again to cancel the +fav it decreases properly by 1.

Example:
[How can you tell what a server actually does?](https://serverfault.com/questions/697638/how-can-you-tell-what-a-server-actually-does/697664#697664)

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure I've reported it in the right place.

Comment: I can  reproduce this, but it also works in the other direction when I unfavorite a question and then favorite it again, the number will increase by 2.

Comment: Thanks @Sven I've added it to the question.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition.  Perhaps it sends a message to the server, *"Un-favorite, and please respond with the current favorite count"* and then subtracts one from the returned favorite count. Incorrectly, since the server probably provides the new favorite count after the user unfavorite is entered into the DB. If sent as two separate messages, it is literally a race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

We had a problem where we were updating the UI, but we weren't actually saving the new favorite count, so it was subtracting 1 from the original number, i.e. instead of `(N + 1) - 1` it was just showing `N - 1` where `N` is the original count.